# How to build Swift project on NixOS?

Tags: swift, gcc, nixos

I'm trying to build a simple Swift project on NixOS. Here are the steps to reproduce:

```
git clone https://github.com/PerfectlySoft/PerfectTemplate.git
cd PerfectTemplate
touch shell.nix
```

Add `shell.nix` with following contents:

```
with import <nixpkgs> {};

stdenv.mkDerivation {
  name = "swift-env";

  buildInputs = [
    openssl
    stdenv
    binutils
    cmake
    pkgconfig
    curl
    glibc
    icu
    libblocksruntime
    libbsd
    libedit
    libuuid
    libxml2
    ncurses
    sqlite
    swig
  ];

}
```

Running `nix-shell --pure shell.nix` and from there `swift build`, gives me:

```
gcc: error: x86_64-unknown-linux: No such file or directory
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-target’
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-fblocks’
gcc: error: x86_64-unknown-linux: No such file or directory
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-fmodules’; did you mean ‘-fmudflap’?
gcc: error: x86_64-unknown-linux: No such file or directory
gcc: error: x86_64-unknown-linux: No such file or directory
gcc: error: x86_64-unknown-linux: No such file or directory
gcc: error: x86_64-unknown-linux: No such file or directory
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-target’
gcc: error: x86_64-unknown-linux: No such file or directory
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-fblocks’
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-target’
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-target’
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-target’
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-fblocks’
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-fmodules’; did you mean ‘-fmudflap’?
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-fblocks’
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-fblocks’
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-fmodules’; did you mean ‘-fmudflap’?
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-target’
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-fmodules’; did you mean ‘-fmudflap’?
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-fmodules’; did you mean ‘-fmudflap’?
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-fblocks’
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-target’
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-fmodule-name=PerfectCZlib’
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-fmodules’; did you mean ‘-fmudflap’?
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-fmodules-cache-path=/home/dmi3y/Dev/Swift/PerfectTemplate/.build/x86_64-unknown-linux/debug/ModuleCache’
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-fblocks’
```

I'd appreciate any help with this as I'm pretty much new to nix-shell and NixOS.

*EDIT*:

I changed my `shell.nix` to this:

```
{ pkgs ? import <nixpkgs> {} }:
pkgs.mkShell {
  name = "swift-env";

  buildInputs = with pkgs; [
    openssl
    clang
    swift
  ];

  shellHook = ''
    CC=clang
  '';
}
```

However, when I run `nix-shell` followed by `swift build`, I'm now getting:

```
[1/25] Compiling PerfectCZlib zutil.c
[2/25] Compiling PerfectCZlib uncompr.c
[3/25] Compiling PerfectCZlib inftrees.c
[4/25] Compiling PerfectCZlib inflate.c
[5/25] Compiling PerfectCZlib trees.c
[6/25] Compiling PerfectCZlib inffast.c
[7/25] Compiling PerfectCZlib infback.c
[8/25] Compiling PerfectCZlib gzwrite.c
/nix/store/iz6k7x3l14ykr56crz3dizas1rrkcyzr-clang-wrapper-7.1.0/resource-root/include/module.modulemap:24:8: error: redefinition of module '_Builtin_intrinsics'

#  warning _FORTIFY_SOURCE requires compiling with optimization (-O)
   ^
1 warning and 3 errors generated.
1 warning and 3 errors generated.
```

Full log can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/C78UUukk).

This is now looks like a missing library dependency or a version conflict.

For the record, here's additional information about my setup that might shed more light:

```
$ nix-channel --list                                                    
home-manager https://github.com/rycee/home-manager/archive/master.tar.gz
nixos https://nixos.org/channels/nixos-19.09  

$ nix-shell --run 'swift -version'                                      
Swift version 5.0.2 (swift-5.0.2-RELEASE)
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnub
```

After searching the web I found a Jira issue for Swift compiler and this [specific comment](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-7065?focusedCommentId=32957&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-32957). I decided to exclude `clang` from dependencies and only include `swift`, since this combination seem to be conflicting:

```
{ pkgs ? import <nixpkgs> {} }:
pkgs.mkShell {
  name = "swift-env";

  buildInputs = with pkgs; [
    openssl
    swift
  ];

  shellHook = ''
    CC=clang
  '';
}
```

And that worked! I was finally able to build the project!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your using the `--pure` option, nothing from your previous environment will be imported into the shell. This includes the `swift` binary itself. So first I would add `swift` to the `buildInputs`.

The error your getting indicates that `gcc` doesn't even understand the command line options being passed. I don't know anything about Swift, but after seeing that I assumed that it needs a different compiler. Sure enough, after a quick search it looks like it is llvm based. You will thus need to also add `clang` to your build inputs. In addition, you'll need to use `mkShell` instead of `mkDerivation` to setup the proper environment.

The former is a wrapper to the latter that is specifically designed to set up a nix-shell, and ensures the environment is handled correctly. You'll need to pass in the `shellHook` attribute to override the default c compiler to `clang` using the `CC` envvar. The `shellHook` is a way of running arbitrary commands at the start of the shell.

As a final note, the `nix-shell` command searches for `shell.nix` by default so you don't have to pass it as an argument. If `shell.nix` does not exist, then it will try `default.nix`. If neither exist, then you'll have to explicitly specify the nix expressions location.

**TLDR**

to put it all together:

```
# a more idiomatic way to import nixpkgs, overridable from the cmdline
{ pkgs ? import <nixpkgs> {} }:
pkgs.mkShell {
  name = "swift-env";

  buildInputs = with pkgs; [
    # your other inputs
    clang
    swift
  ];

  shellHook = ''
    CC=clang
  '';
}
```

Just to be sure my logic was correct I downloaded the repo and gave it go. Everything compiles and runs successfully.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and thorough explanations! I updated my question according to your suggestions but still getting a compilation error. I wonder how it worked for you and whether you included any additional libraries that I don't have?
I'll keep trying though. Thanks again for your answer!

Comment: Well in my successful build, I included all the `buildInputs` from your original post. Looks like you trimmed it down to just 3. Perhaps you trimmed it a bit too much. Try it with the full list first, and then try removing entries one by one to trim it down to just the bare minimum.